# panic: error parsing uri: scheme must be "mongodb" or "mongodb+srv" Golang - MongoDB connection error

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, connection

This is the error I am getting when I **docker-compose up** my app in docker-desktop.

```
{ { }}
panic: error parsing uri: scheme must be "mongodb" or "mongodb+srv"
goroutine 1 [running]:
go-products/database.ConnectDB(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/app/database/database.go:15 +0x145
main.main()
/app/main.go:14 +0x13d
```

Here is my **main.go** file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "go-products/config"
    "go-products/database"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    conf := config.GetConfig()
    fmt.Println(conf)
    db := database.ConnectDB(conf.Mongo)
    fmt.Println(db)
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

This is the **database** file where I try to make connection.

```
package database

import (
    "context"
    "go-products/config"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func ConnectDB(conf config.MongoConfiguration) *mongo.Database {
    connection := options.Client().ApplyURI(conf.Server)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), connection)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return client.Database(conf.Database)
}
```

**config.go** file

```
package config

import "github.com/spf13/viper"

type Configuration struct {
    Environment string
    Mongo       MongoConfiguration
}

type MongoConfiguration struct {
    Server string
    Database string
    Collection string
}

func GetConfig() Configuration {
    conf := Configuration{}
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.SetConfigType("yml")
    viper.AddConfigPath("./config")

    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return conf
}
```

this is **config.yaml** file.

```
environment: dev
mongo:
  server: mongodb://mongo:27017
  database: Mgo
  collection: Products
```

I have checked the official documentation and some resources but couldn't find a way to handle this in **Golang** environment. What should I change here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GetConfig()` function, you declare a variable of type `Configuration`, and you return it, but you never actually assign anything to any of its fields.  That's why your `fmt.Println()` call to dump out the configuration just shows `{ { }}`; none of the fields have assigned values.

You need to [unmarshal](https://github.com/spf13/viper#unmarshaling) the Viper configuration into the config structure:

```go
func GetConfig() (Configuration, error) {
    var conf Configuration
    // ... viper setup ...

    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return Configuration{}, err
    }

    // *** unmarshal the Viper config into the Configuration struct ***
    err = viper.Unmarshal(&conf)
    if err != nil {
        return Configuration{}, err
    }
    // ***

    return conf, nil
}
```